# display result - data from 1 column divided into 2 columns depending on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, toad

Hello i need help here...

my query shows the folllowing result:

```
Id      name           color    Version
1       leather        black      1
1       leather        brown      2
2       suede          brown      1
3       cloth          green      1
3       cloth          blue       2
```

i want to display the following:

```
Id      name           color    Color_2    
1       leather        black      brown     
2       suede          brown      
3       cloth          green      blue
```

query is simple
currently

```
SELECT ID, NAME, COLOR,VERSION
FROM table1,table2  
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID 
AND id in 
    (SELECT ID 
    FROM table1,table2 
    WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID  
    AND VERSION in ('1'))
AND VERSION in ('1','2')
```

Comment: Please show us your schema (table structure) for `Table1` and `Table2`.  Do you need a code that will work both in `MySQL` and `Oracle`?

Comment: Is `maximum` number of colors assigned to a particular name known at design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one (if you know at design time the maximum number of colors you could possibly have)

```
drop table my_test;

create table my_test (
  id          number,
  name        varchar2(32),
  color       varchar2(32),
  version     number);

insert into my_test values(1,'leather','black',1);
insert into my_test values(1,'leather','brown',2);
insert into my_test values(2,'suede','brown',1);
insert into my_test values(3,'cloth','green',1);
insert into my_test values(3,'cloth','blue ',2);

set linesize 200
select min(id) id,
       name,
       max(decode(version,1,color,null)) color,
       max(decode(version,2,color,null)) color_2
  from my_test
 group by name
 order by 1;

        ID NAME       COLOR      COLOR_2   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 leather    black      brown     
         2 suede      brown                
         3 cloth      green      blue      

3 rows selected.
```

This will work with any Oracle database version. Depending on the version you use, look at the LISTAGG, WM_CONCAT and the like ([here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php))

Comment: i dont want to insert anything in the DB... all i want is to modify the current query and display the result as desired.. i really appreciate your help....

Answer (score 0):

You're a little all over the place with your database type...is it mysql or oracle?  I'm guessing oracle by your select statement anyway.   I'm using 'join' based syntax, I find it easier to read than what you have here.  Take a select statement with version 1 and left join it to a select statement with version 2.  If there is a version three, put another join in there.

```
select a.id, a.name, a.colour, b.colour
from (select * from table1 where version = 1) a
left join (select * from table1 where version = 2) b
 on a.id = b.id
```

(this assumes version 1 always exists and there can't be a version 2 without a version 1)

Comment: let me reframe the question -- it is oracle.. it all from the same table the color also ...                                          SELECT tabble1.ID, table1.NAME, table1.COLOR,table1.VERSION
FROM table1,table2  
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID 
AND id in 
    (SELECT ID 
    FROM table1,table2 
    WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID  
    AND VERSION in ('1'))
AND VERSION in ('1','2')

Answer (score 0):

let me reframe the question -- it is oracle.. it all from the same table the color also ...                                          SELECT tabble1.ID, table1.NAME, table1.COLOR,table1.VERSION
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID 
AND id in 
    (SELECT ID 
    FROM table1,table2 
    WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID
    AND VERSION in ('1'))
AND VERSION in ('1','2')